# Join in Django ORM

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-orm

I want to perform a Django Join operation. How can I do that?

My models are:-

```
class ShipmentScanMapping(models.Model):
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    shipment_id = models.ForeignKey('Shipment',related_name ='scans')

class ShipmentPPTLMapping(models.Model):
    pptl_id = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    shipment_id = models.ForeignKey('Shipment', related_name = 'pptls')

class Shipment(models.Model):
    job_id = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    time = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add = True, db_index = True)
```

My query in SQL is :-

```
select * from data_shipmentpptlmapping inner join data_shipmentscanmapping where data_shipmentpptlmapping.shipment_id = data_shipmentscanmapping.shipment_id and data_shipmentscanmapping.barcode = 'xyzabc';
```

I want to get those objects which have `barcode = 'xyzabc'` and then reference key `shipment_id` of datashipmentscanmapping = shipment_id of datashipmentpptlmapping.

I'm currently doing.

```
shipment_scan_obj = ShipmentScanMapping.objects.filter(barcode = barcode).values('shipment_id')['shipment_id']
if shipment_scan_obj:
            shipment_pptl_mapping_obj = ShipmentPPTLMapping.objects.filter(shipment_id__in = shipment_id_list)
            if shipment_pptl_mapping_obj:
                    .....do something......
```

Here's what I tried . It throws an error aying `Cannot resolve keyword 'shipmentscanmapping' into field.`:-

```
shipment_pptl_mapping_obj = ShipmentPPTLMapping.objects.filter(shipmentscanmapping__barcode = barcode,shipment_id = shipmentscanmapping__shipment_id)
        if shipment_pptl_mapping_obj:
              ......dosomething.......
```

How can I perform a join operation in Django ORM?

Comment: Can you show the relevant Model subclasses in models.py?  At least the relevant field definitions.

Comment: Ohh. I'll just uppdate it.

Comment: I just updated it. Kindly have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django you can only join across foreign key relationships (or many to many, or reverse foreign keys).  In this case you can join through the Shipment class to get to ShipmentScanMapping.  Try this:

```
ShipmentPPTLMapping.objects.filter(shipment_id__scans__barcode="xyzabc")
```

This says "find all the `ShipmentPPTLMapping` objects that refer to `Shipments` that have `scans` (`ShipmentScanMapping` objects) with the barcode 'xyzabc'".

This is not the only way to do this; you could use a more complex subquery system to skip the intermediate step of accessing the Shipment table.  Here's a possible example of a subquery approach (this is more complex and more unusual, so I'm less confident this code is correct!):

```
ShipmentPPTLMapping.objects.filter(shipment_id__in=Shipment.filter(scans__barcode="xyzabc"))
```

This could also conceivably work and not touch the Shipment table at all, possibly at the cost of doing two relatively fast queries in turn, but caveat coder:

```
ShipmentPPTLMapping.objects.filter(shipment_id__in=ShipmentScanMapping.objects.filter(barcode="xyzabc").values_list('shipment_id', flat=True))
```

Doing it as a join through Shipment is the clearest and most straightforward way to express this desire in Django.  Whichever method you use I recommend taking a peek at the SQL being generated by the ORM (through introspection or logging) to make sure you understand what's going on underneath the hood.

By the way, I recommend not using "shipment_id" as the name of your foreign key, because Django automatically adds an "_id" to the end of the field name to keep track of the ID -- the _id-less name refers to the row on the other side of the foreign key, as opposed to just the numeric ID.  Instead just call it "shipment".

Comment: May I know the complex way of doing it. Because joining 3 tables might actually take a lot of time (as per my code).

Comment: I am pretty sure the multiple join will be fast, but I'll take a stab at adding a subquery method example to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
ShipmentScanMapping.objects.filter(barcode = barcode).values('shipment_id')['shipment_id']
```

I think problem comes from here, `values` return a `ValuesQuerySet` which seems to be an array of dict: [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values). So you can loop on it like this

```
arr = ShipmentScanMapping.objects.filter(barcode = barcode).values('shipment_id')
for element in arr:
    print element ['shipment_id']
```